# How to reference node in Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm using gdscipt and I'm trying to set up a state machine. I'm trying to access `PlayerStateMachine/PlayerStateMachineManager.gd`

by using

`onready var statemachine = get_node("PlayerStateMachine/PlayerStateMachineManager.gd")`

but I keep getting the error

`get_node: (Node not found: "PlayerStateMachine/PlayerStateMachineManager.gd" (absolute path attempted from "/root/Player").)`

From what I understand, `get_node()` should look for the path from the parent of the current node, so why is it not finding `PlayerStateMachineManager.gd`?

FYI: `PlayerStateMachine` is a folder in the same folder as `Player.gd`

[Directory Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Koct0.png)

Answer (score 3):

The [`get_node`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-get-node) method will try to get a node form the scene tree (or fail with an error). However, apparently you are passing a path to a script file (e.g. with extension ".gd")? Files are in the FileSystem tree, not the Scene tree.

To be clear: a script is not a [`Node`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html), and a `Node` is not a script (nor script file). `Node`s exist in the scene tree, and might - or might not - have a script attached to them. *An script could be attached to an [`Object`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html), multiple `Objects`s, or none. And yes, `Node`s are `Object`s*

You can add `Node`s to the scene tree from code using [`add_child`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-add-child), and the components of the path in the scene tree are the [`name`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-property-name)s of the `Node`s. *You can also modify the scene tree of a scene file (e.g. with extension ".tscn"), which you can do visually in the Godot editor.*

To reiterate: adding a `Node` does not imply adding a script file. And the way you organize the script files does not have to match the scene tree. Furthermore, you can have scripts that are not attached to `Node`s.

Under the assumption that you want a `Node` (and not a script file), you need the path to it in the scene tree. *I cannot tell you which is the path, because you did not share how your scene tree looks like.*

In the editor the Scene tree looks something like this:

[image: Scene]

And `get_node` uses paths in the that tree.

See [Nodes and scene instances](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/nodes_and_scene_instances.html)

---

Alternatively you do want to load a script file. After all, the image you shared is of the file system tree (except this picture is not of the Godot editor):

[image: Files]

You can load these script files using [`load`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-load) (or [`preload`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-preload) or `ResourceLoader.load` or `ResourceLoader.load_interactive`…) giving you a [`Script`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_script.html). If it is a GDScript script file, it is a [`GDScript`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_gdscript.html#class-gdscript). *Which are `Object`s too.* And you can instantiate that `GDScript` with [`new`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-new)…

From the point of view of the GDScript language, `Script`s are classes. However, behind the scenes what happens is that when you instantiate a `GDScript` Godot will create an `Object` the appropriate type (`Node` or not) and attaches the `GDScript` to it. *Notice that the `Object` class has [`get_script`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-get-script) and [`set_script`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-set-script) methods.*

Be aware that Godot packages and virtualices the project file system. So you would use a path starting with "res://" to refer to the files in the project file system, which are actual files while you are editing the game, or virtual files inside the ".pck" file you get once you exported the game.

See [File system](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/filesystem.html) and [File paths in Godot projects](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/io/data_paths.html#doc-data-paths)

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend to the answer of Theraot:

If your script is attached to your PlayerStateMachine Node you can access it via the node.

So as an example, if you have a function change_state() in your PlayerStateMachineManager.gd and your SceneTree looks like this:

```
Player -> Player.gd attached
  PlayerStateMachine -> PlayerStateMachineManager.gd attached
```

you can do something like this in the player script:

```
var statemanager

func _ready()
   statemanager = $PlayerStateMachine # same as get_node("PlayerStateMachine")
   statemanager.change_state("idle")
```